# Average of a cycle of a signal - Python

Tags: python

I have a approximately cyclic smoothed signal. This is shown in the figure[image: []

I would like to find the average of a cycle, say between the two minima as shown by the grey lines in the figure. How could it be done?

here is my newbie attempt (very inelegant) at finding the minima indexes:

```
#find minima
f= data
start =0
end = len(f)/10
step =len(f)/10

while end < len(f):
    minVal = min(f[start:end])
    end = end +step
    start = start +step
    for i,j in enumerate(f):
        if j == minVal:
            print i,j
```

you can find the data at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nss1sz7jkzth0lo/data.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do will require a bit of calc knowledge. Cyclic functions can be viewed either in the time domain f(t) or the frequency domain f(F) you go between them using a Fourier transform (technically a discrete Fourier transform) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform
Once you have done this, the only thing you need to do is find the max of f(F): the frequency most present in the wave. This will give you the size to find the average over.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- period is determined from the data using Fourier transform
- with codes (still long though)

```
# assuming the data is a dataframe df with time & signal
t = df.time
x = df.signal

ft = np.fft.rfft(x)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(x), t[1]-t[0]) # Get frequency axis from the time axis
mags = abs(ft) # We don't care about the phase information here

# get period / freq at which mags is largest (major frequency, not noise)
p = 1/freqs[mags.argmax()]
print(p)

# split data based on period of p (estimated above)
ls= [df[i*p:(i+1)*p] for i in range(0,int(df.shape[0]/p))]

# make new index [0,1,2...] for each segmented data to used in next step
ls = [d.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'time'}) for d in ls]

# TODO: ensure number of rows is the same for all cycles

# re-estimate time to 0 -- end_period
for d in ls:
    d.time = d.time-d.time[0]

# re-combine data
df_new = pd.concat(ls).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'tID'})

# evaluate average
dfavg = df_new.groupby('tID').mean()

# reset_index to time if preferred
dfavg = dfavg.set_index('time')
```